# Traceback with FastAPI when loading a machine learning model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, fastapi, uvicorn

I am trying to load my model from tensorflow and then process it with FastAPI, but I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\Documents\Projects\Adenocarcionoma detection\api\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File
  File "C:\Python 3.9.6\lib\site-packages\fastapi\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .applications import FastAPI as FastAPI
  File "C:\Python 3.9.6\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 16, in <module>
    from fastapi import routing
  File "C:\Python 3.9.6\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 22, in <module>
    from fastapi import params
  File "C:\Python 3.9.6\lib\site-packages\fastapi\params.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pydantic.fields import FieldInfo
  File "C:\Python 3.9.6\lib\site-packages\pydantic\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import dataclasses
  File "C:\Python 3.9.6\lib\site-packages\pydantic\dataclasses.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ._internal import _config, _decorators, _typing_extra
  File "C:\Python 3.9.6\lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_decorators.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ..fields import ComputedFieldInfo
  File "C:\Python 3.9.6\lib\site-packages\pydantic\fields.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import types
  File "C:\Python 3.9.6\lib\site-packages\pydantic\types.py", line 34, in <module>
    from ._internal import (
  File "C:\Python 3.9.6\lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_fields.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _typing_extra
  File "C:\Python 3.9.6\lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_typing_extra.py", line 13, in <module>
    from typing_extensions import Annotated, Final, Literal, TypeAliasType, TypeGuard, get_args, get_origin
ImportError: cannot import name 'TypeAliasType' from 'typing_extensions' (C:\Python 3.9.6\lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py)
```

This is my code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File
import uvicorn
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf

app = FastAPI()

MODEL = tf.keras.models.load_model("../Saved_models/1")
CLASS_NAMES = ["Adenocarcinoma", "Large Cell Carcinoma", "Normal", "Squamous Cell Carcinoma"]


@app.get("/ping")
async def ping():
    return "Hello, I am alive"


# Takes the bytes as an input and returns an ndarray as an output
def read_file_as_image(data):
    image = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(data)))
    return image


@app.post("/predict")
async def predict(
        file: UploadFile = File(...)
):
    image = read_file_as_image(await file.read())
    img_batch = np.expand_dims(image, 0)
    predictions = MODEL.predict(img_batch)
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=8000)
```

I don't know what that traceback means, is that a dependencies problem?

My tensorflow and tensorflow-serving-api are 2.5.0, basically the model is trying to process an image from a computed tomography and predict if it is an adenocarcinoma or not

Comment: The error is that Pydantic needs the type `TypeAliasType` from the `typing_extensions` module (which is a module for backporting typing stuff to earlier python versions). If you run `pip freeze`, what is the version of `typing_extensions`? It seems like `TypeAliasType` was [added in version 4.6.0](https://github.com/python/typing_extensions/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#release-460-may-22-2023)

Comment: My `typing_extension` version is 4.7.1.Maybe a problem with fastapi?